# Update UI from a background worker

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

I want to port my client from Java Swing(`Java client`) to Android(`Android client`).

Basically, my `Java client` have a thread, which run a forever while loop to receive UDP packets, and base on content of UDP packets, UI of the corresponding JFrame will be updated.

Now I want my `Android client` has a `background worker` like the thread in the `Java client`, and that `worker` will be initialized in the `main activity`. Then when there are some requests from the UDP socket, the `main activity` will start some corresponding activities (Chat Activities), then there are some other requests come from the UDP socket, `the worker` will update on the activity(this activity can be main activity or a Chat Activity) which is being displayed on the screen.

So my question is what the `background worker` should be:

- Service
- Normal Java thread
- Asynctask
- or what...

Which is the most appropriate with my requirements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background worker should be a service, because

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.

while your UI will be a activity, your service will read the UDP packets and the activity will be modified accordingly.

Comment: thank you, but I have an additional question: how can a service update UI of many different activities. For example: a service reads the UDP packets to get messages, then how it send those messages to different activities?

Comment: you can bind an activity to a service using bindService. It will give you access to an IBinder that you use to access things in the service

Comment: you can use Intents to update activity when you recieve UDP packets in your service.

Comment: @njzk2 sorry, but I want service accesses things in the activity, not otherwise

Comment: @rao_555 you mean Intent.putExtra ?

Comment: @LeoLink : you can. Basically you can define an AIDL interface in which you have a method to allow the registration of a listener (also an AIDL interface)

Comment: @njzk2 do you have any ideas else, because I have ever heard about AIDL, but it seems too complex to me :(

Comment: the alternative is what rao_555 suggest, use intents. for example, you can send broadcasts to announce changes, and register receivers when appropriate

Comment: @njzk2 so you mean: I have to register different broadcast strings for every Chat Activity, then based on the received message through UDP socket, the service will broadcast a message with the corresponding action, then that message will be received by the corresponding ChatActivity. Am I right? (sorry, my english is not good, i know :(

Comment: that would work, yes. you can use intentFilters to direct the broadcast to the specific activity

Comment: @LeoLink you can use broadcast intents. The service will broadcast an intent using sendBroadcast() on recieving UDP packets. while the activities will register as BroadcastReciever using registerReciever(), this will activities to respond to broadcasts from service.

Answer (score 0):

A [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is the most suitable candidate in your case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class Application class for each android application . First extend it and it will be initialized on very first time your app will start even before your Activity . Initialize/ start your normal java thread to perfrom background work here . The key advantage will be you can get instance of this application class anywhere from the app (It means you can control on the background thread from anywhere in the applicaion . Send background http request etc.. whatever ....) .Then initialize the handler on the UI thread of particular activity upon which you want to do changes and do something like this.

```
                 private Handler myHandler ; 

                  public void checkBackgroundAndUpdateUi()
                  {
                    if(conetxt.getApplicationContext().getStatus == completed)
                    {
                       initializeHandler();
                        handler.postRunnable(myRunnable);

                    }
                  }
             Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){

                public void run()
                 {

                  // update your UI views here .....

                 }
             };

             private void initializeHandler(){
               myHandler = new Handler ();
             }
```

Comment: I thought about it already, but I was stuck at thinking of: how can the thread in the Application class access different Handlers in different activities (or different UI threads)?

Comment: This is horrible. Avoid it unless you can't. It implies having everything referenced in the application object

Comment: Thread cannot access different handlers ture, but Handlers in different class can access this thread . I think its a kind of client server communication in which thread in application class is only used to send request and handlers in activity class are used to get response back and update in UI.

Comment: One more thing services should be only used when your app wants to perform something in BACKGROUND not when you want to do something netwrok related work in other thread . i mean to say other than UI thread. Example of services you can take it of as music players even playing  music in background. see the link for your reference .     http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html